# hy elect lower priority node master?

Tags: mongodb, vote

mongod:3.2.12

os:centos 6.4

A and B node are in the same room，C node in other room ，A.priority=10,B.priority=5,C.priority=1,on the primary node A：cfg=rs.conf();cfg.members[B.node.id].priority=15;rs.reconfig(cfg);

A node and B node log：VoteRequester: Got no vote from xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy because: candidate's data is staler than mine, resp.

but node C  is primary

node A and node B continue to try in Starting an election for a priority takeover,but failed to be primary

Q1: why the higher priority node A or node B not elected for master?

Comment: The reason is given in the log message: "candidate's data is staler than mine". A higher priority node cannot be elected if it is too far behind the current primary: this would force some write operations to be [rolled back](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks). A higher priority member needs to reduce replication lag before it is eligible to be elected as primary. Can you edit your question description to include the output of `rs.status()` from the primary and the member configured with the highest priority? Can you also include the protocol version from `rs.conf()`?

Comment: thanks Stennie.  first. the rs.conf() command output : protocolVersion:NumberLong(1).  because,this is produce system,when it happened ,i immediately rollback my operation.so i am sorry that i fogot record the output of rs.status() from primary and the member configured with the highest priority. but the output of rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo() from primary and candidate node i executed  showes that  :

Comment: source: A node
        syncedTo: Mon Jun 24 2018 16:55:08 GMT+0800 (CST)
        0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary 
source: B node
        syncedTo: Mon Jun 24 2018 16:55:09 GMT+0800 (CST)
        -1 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary 
source: C node
        syncedTo: Mon Jun 24 2018 16:55:08 GMT+0800 (CST)
        0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary